# Accessing Another Directory with Wordpress Installed

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have Wordpress installed on a shared host at Site5. It's installed in the root directory:
www.domain.com

I have another directory that I want to be able to access outside of the Wordpress site:
www.domain.com/directory/

When I visit this URL, I get Wordpress's 404-page. The .htaccess file, as modified by WP, reads:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I assume I need an edit to the .htaccess file to access this directory?

Answer (score 0):

Edit .htaccess present inside "directory"

It should be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /directory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion -- modifying "directory" to the name of the actual directory and it didn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Access www.domain.com/directory/wp-admin. If this is not accessible. delete .htaccess content from root location. Click Settings> Permalinks. Save your desired Permalink and wordpress should suggest the content of .htaccess.

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I was out of the country. I tried your suggestion with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out -- in case it helps someone else. I was attempting to password protect the directory, too, which I left out of the question as I didn't realize it was part of the issue. The solution is here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/mod-rewrite-conflicting-with-other-htaccess-files